# How to write on the second line in a .txt file (java)

Tags: java, file, formatting, filewriter

I want to write a few arguments in a .txt file and I want to sort them. To do that I want to go to the next line for every groop of arguments but I dont know how to do that.I have tried the:
    `x.nextLine();`
statement, but that is only for scanning and not for formatting.

How can I go to the next line of a file while formatting? Is there another statement for that?

This is the code I created:

```
try{
    w = new Formatter("data.txt");
}
catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatal Error, please Reboot or reinstal program", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

w.format("%s,%s,%s,%s%n", book,code,author,editor);
w.close();
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Perhaps if you provided some examples what you're trying to do with the data it would help.

Comment: We need to see actual code to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Do you want to sort them in the file correct? Is that also what you mean by 'formatting'? What class is the 'x' in the x.nextLine();?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8puE0508   here you go

Comment: the x in nextline means the pointer to the file. formating is writing in java

Comment: I pasted the code from the pastebin into the question (which is the proper way of doing things here on SO).  However, now there is a pretty strong discrepancy between the text and the code, you may want to adjust the text to ensure the entire question makes sense.

Comment: @fvu I don't understand that. how can i make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

```
w.format("%s,%s,%s,%s%n", book,code,author,editor);
```

and I assume you want a newline where you write %n.   But newline is \n, so change your code to

```
w.format("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", book,code,author,editor);
```

Also, you may want to revise the error catching logic in the program: right now if opening the file fails, you show an error message, which is good, but after that your program continues execution and will crash and burn on the first write operation...

EDIT: every time you execute the line `w.format("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", book,code,author,editor);` a line terminated by a new line will be added to the file, as long as you don't close the file or restart the program, because the [Javadoc for the constructor you use says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.String%29):

> fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then ***it will be truncated to zero size***; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

So, if you need a file that grows instead of being overwritten you should use one of the other available constructors, eg one [accepting an Appendable as argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.Appendable%29).  This would lead to the following code:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("data.txt",true);
Formatter w = new Formatter(fstream);

// do whatever your program needs to do

w.close();
```

Of course surrounded by the necessary exception handling.

Comment: okey thank you I woll end the program after the error massage and i will be fine

Comment: I's still not what I ment. I'm sorry for the late comment but my internet was down. I ment that i need to write to it multaple times (so not formatting, before I didn't know that formatting ment) how can I make it write multaple times to it

Comment: @codermaster have a look at my edit, does that solve your problem?

Comment: so the second line actualy writes to it.

Comment: @codermaster do you mean you now get the result you need?

Comment: No I ment if the second line of code writes to the file?